# How can I call my windows form elements in my other class in C#

Tags: c#

I want to acces a combobox, a chart,... form my form. This is automatically added in my Form1. But now I need the combobox, chart... in another class. How can I reference this to the class DeviceClass? Do I have to make the combobox and others public in my form? Thanks for the help by advance. I tried in DeviceClass to put it like this:
private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cboChannels; bit it doesn' work. I think I need to make public it in other way in my from. or do I have to use a return in form?

```
public class Form1 : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    DeviceClass d = new DeviceClass();
    #region "Windows Form Designer generated code"
    public void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea chartArea1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartArea();
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series series1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series();
        this.tabControl1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabControl();
        this.tabPage1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TabPage();
        this.grpDevice = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.btnInitialise = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.cmbdevice = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.lblDevice = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.grpAnalogOut = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.btnApplyOutputSettings = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.txtClockFreqFile = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblClockFreqFile = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblChListSize = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.txtCglSize = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.lblChListEntry = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.cboEntry = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.lblOutputSignal = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.cboSignalType = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.btnAddModifyOutputChannels = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.cboChannels = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.lblOutputChannel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.groupBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.lblWaveClockFreq = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.txtDaClockFreq = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.txtBufferSize = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.lblOutputBufferSize = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.groupBox3 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.lblOutputFreq = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.txtOutputFrequency = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.grpAnalogInput = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.lblNumOfCh = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.btnApplyInputSettings = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.grpDataAcqMode = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        this.lblSyncMode = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.cmbSyncMode = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.btnSetNumOfCh = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.cmbNumOfCh = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.grpChSettings = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.OlBufferDataGrid)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tabControl1
        // 
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
        this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1054, 625);
        this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 92;
        // 
        // tabPage1
        // 
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.grpDevice);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.grpAnalogOut);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.grpAnalogInput);
        this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 22);
        this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
        this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1046, 599);
        this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.tabPage1.Text = "Setup";
        this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // grpDevice
        // 
        this.grpDevice.Controls.Add(this.btnInitialise);
        this.grpDevice.Controls.Add(this.cmbdevice);
        this.grpDevice.Controls.Add(this.lblDevice);
        this.grpDevice.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 5);
        this.grpDevice.Name = "grpDevice";
        this.grpDevice.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(467, 46);
        this.grpDevice.TabIndex = 97;
        this.grpDevice.TabStop = false;
        this.grpDevice.Text = "Device settings";
        // 
        // btnInitialise
        // 
        this.btnInitialise.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(351, 16);
        this.btnInitialise.Name = "btnInitialise";
        this.btnInitialise.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 25);
        this.btnInitialise.TabIndex = 21;
        this.btnInitialise.Text = "Initialize";
        this.btnInitialise.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnInitialise_Click_1);
        // 
        // cmbdevice
        // 
        this.cmbdevice.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.cmbdevice.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(197, 18);
        this.cmbdevice.Name = "cmbdevice";
        this.cmbdevice.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(117, 21);
        this.cmbdevice.TabIndex = 63;
        // 
        // lblDevice
        // 
        this.lblDevice.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblDevice.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(21, 22);
        this.lblDevice.Name = "lblDevice";
        this.lblDevice.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 13);
        this.lblDevice.TabIndex = 62;
        this.lblDevice.Text = "Device:";
        this.lblDevice.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        // 
        // grpAnalogOut
        // 
        this.grpAnalogOut.Controls.Add(this.btnApplyOutputSettings);
        this.grpAnalogOut.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
        this.grpAnalogOut.Controls.Add(this.groupBox2);
        this.grpAnalogOut.Controls.Add(this.groupBox3);
        this.grpAnalogOut.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(478, 56);
        this.grpAnalogOut.Name = "grpAnalogOut";
        this.grpAnalogOut.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(467, 298);
        this.grpAnalogOut.TabIndex = 96;
        this.grpAnalogOut.TabStop = false;
        this.grpAnalogOut.Text = "Analog Output";
        // 
        // btnApplyOutputSettings
        // 
        this.btnApplyOutputSettings.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 255);
        this.btnApplyOutputSettings.Name = "btnApplyOutputSettings";
        this.btnApplyOutputSettings.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(142, 32);
        this.btnApplyOutputSettings.TabIndex = 109;
        this.btnApplyOutputSettings.Text = "Apply Output Settings";
        // 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.txtClockFreqFile);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.lblClockFreqFile);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.lblChListSize);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.txtCglSize);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.lblChListEntry);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.cboEntry);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.lblOutputSignal);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.cboSignalType);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.btnAddModifyOutputChannels);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.cboChannels);
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.lblOutputChannel);
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 114);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(434, 136);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 108;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "Channel List Setup";
        // 
        // txtClockFreqFile
        // 
        this.txtClockFreqFile.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(342, 55);
        this.txtClockFreqFile.Name = "txtClockFreqFile";
        this.txtClockFreqFile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 20);
        this.txtClockFreqFile.TabIndex = 110;
        // 
        // lblClockFreqFile
        // 
        this.lblClockFreqFile.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(228, 49);
        this.lblClockFreqFile.Name = "lblClockFreqFile";
        this.lblClockFreqFile.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 31);
        this.lblClockFreqFile.TabIndex = 109;
        this.lblClockFreqFile.Text = "Clock frequency output file:";
        // 
        // lblChListSize
        // 
        this.lblChListSize.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(228, 25);
        this.lblChListSize.Name = "lblChListSize";
        this.lblChListSize.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 16);
        this.lblChListSize.TabIndex = 107;
        this.lblChListSize.Text = "Channel List Size :";
        // 
        // txtCglSize
        // 
        this.txtCglSize.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.txtCglSize.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(342, 26);
        this.txtCglSize.Name = "txtCglSize";
        this.txtCglSize.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 16);
        this.txtCglSize.TabIndex = 106;
        // 
        // lblChListEntry
        // 
        this.lblChListEntry.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 24);
        this.lblChListEntry.Name = "lblChListEntry";
        this.lblChListEntry.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(56, 16);
        this.lblChListEntry.TabIndex = 105;
        this.lblChListEntry.Text = "Entry :";
        this.lblChListEntry.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        // 
        // cboEntry
        // 
        this.cboEntry.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.cboEntry.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(115, 24);
        this.cboEntry.Name = "cboEntry";
        this.cboEntry.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(87, 21);
        this.cboEntry.TabIndex = 104;
        // 
        // lblOutputSignal
        // 
        this.lblOutputSignal.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 96);
        this.lblOutputSignal.Name = "lblOutputSignal";
        this.lblOutputSignal.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 24);
        this.lblOutputSignal.TabIndex = 103;
        this.lblOutputSignal.Text = "Signal Type:";
        this.lblOutputSignal.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        // 
        // cboSignalType
        // 
        this.cboSignalType.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.cboSignalType.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(115, 96);
        this.cboSignalType.Name = "cboSignalType";
        this.cboSignalType.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(87, 21);
        this.cboSignalType.TabIndex = 102;
        // 
        // btnAddModifyOutputChannels
        // 
        this.btnAddModifyOutputChannels.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(326, 85);
        this.btnAddModifyOutputChannels.Name = "btnAddModifyOutputChannels";
        this.btnAddModifyOutputChannels.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(96, 32);
        this.btnAddModifyOutputChannels.TabIndex = 101;
        this.btnAddModifyOutputChannels.Text = "Add/Modify";
        // 
        // cboChannels
        // 
        this.cboChannels.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.cboChannels.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(115, 59);
        this.cboChannels.Name = "cboChannels";
        this.cboChannels.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(87, 21);
        this.cboChannels.TabIndex = 99;
        // 
        // lblOutputChannel
        // 
        this.lblOutputChannel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 56);
        this.lblOutputChannel.Name = "lblOutputChannel";
        this.lblOutputChannel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 16);
        this.lblOutputChannel.TabIndex = 100;
        this.lblOutputChannel.Text = "Channel :";
        this.lblOutputChannel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        //
        // lblWaveClockFreq
        // 
        this.lblWaveClockFreq.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 26);
        this.lblWaveClockFreq.Name = "lblWaveClockFreq";
        this.lblWaveClockFreq.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 16);
        this.lblWaveClockFreq.TabIndex = 7;
        this.lblWaveClockFreq.Text = "D/A Clock Freq :";
        this.lblWaveClockFreq.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
        // 
        // txtDaClockFreq
        // 
        this.txtDaClockFreq.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 24);
        this.txtDaClockFreq.Name = "txtDaClockFreq";
        this.txtDaClockFreq.ReadOnly = true;
        this.txtDaClockFreq.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 20);
        this.txtDaClockFreq.TabIndex = 12;
        // 
        // txtBufferSize
        // 
        this.txtBufferSize.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(122, 49);
        this.txtBufferSize.Name = "txtBufferSize";
        this.txtBufferSize.ReadOnly = true;
        this.txtBufferSize.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 20);
        this.txtBufferSize.TabIndex = 103;
        // 
        // lblOutputBufferSize
        // 
        this.lblOutputBufferSize.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 50);
        this.lblOutputBufferSize.Name = "lblOutputBufferSize";
        this.lblOutputBufferSize.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 16);
        this.lblOutputBufferSize.TabIndex = 102;
        this.lblOutputBufferSize.Text = "Buffer Size :";
        this.lblOutputBufferSize.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

        // 
        // lblSyncMode
        // 
        this.lblSyncMode.AutoSize = true;
        this.lblSyncMode.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 23);
        this.lblSyncMode.Name = "lblSyncMode";
        this.lblSyncMode.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(64, 13);
        this.lblSyncMode.TabIndex = 2;
        this.lblSyncMode.Text = "Sync Mode:";
        // 
        // cmbSyncMode
        // 
        this.cmbSyncMode.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(87, 21);
        this.cmbSyncMode.Name = "cmbSyncMode";
        this.cmbSyncMode.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 21);
        this.cmbSyncMode.TabIndex = 91;
        this.cmbSyncMode.Text = "Not supported";
        //
        // Form1
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1190, 618);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tabControl1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.tabControl1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpDevice.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpDevice.PerformLayout();
        this.grpAnalogOut.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
        this.groupBox2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox2.PerformLayout();
        this.groupBox3.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.groupBox3.PerformLayout();
        this.grpAnalogInput.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpAnalogInput.PerformLayout();
        this.grpDataAcqMode.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpDataAcqMode.PerformLayout();
        this.grpChSettings.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpChSettings.PerformLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.nudChGain)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.nudChNum)).EndInit();
        this.grpClock.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpClock.PerformLayout();
        this.grpBuffering.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpBuffering.PerformLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.nudNumOfBuffers)).EndInit();
        this.tabPage2.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.tabPage2.PerformLayout();
        this.grpAcqVal.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpAcqVal.PerformLayout();
        this.grpAcqDuration.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.grpAcqDuration.PerformLayout();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.nudFiniteDuration)).EndInit();
        this.grpPlot.ResumeLayout(false);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.chart1)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.OlBufferDataGrid)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }
    private TabControl tabControl1;
    private TabPage tabPage1;
    private GroupBox grpDevice;
    private Button btnInitialise;
    private ComboBox cmbdevice;
    private Label lblDevice;
    private GroupBox grpAnalogOut;
    private NumericUpDown nudNumOfBuffers;
    private Label lblNumOfBuffers;
    private Label lblSamplesPerBuffer;
    private TextBox txtSamplesPerBuffer;
    private TabPage tabPage2;
    private CheckBox chkEnableOutput;
    private CheckBox chkEnableInput;
    private GroupBox grpAcqVal;
    private RadioButton rdoHexadecimal;
    private RadioButton rdoDecimal;
    private RadioButton rdoWriteToFile;
    private Label lblStop;
    private Label lblStart;
    private GroupBox grpAcqDuration;
    private NumericUpDown nudFiniteDuration;
    private Label lblDuration;
    private Label lblTimePassed;
    private RadioButton rdoContinuous;
    private RadioButton rdoFinite;
    private GroupBox grpPlot;
    private ComboBox cmbPlotChNum;
    public System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chart1;
    private DateTimePicker dtpMeasurementStop;
    private DateTimePicker dtpMeasurementStart;
    private Button btnSetMeasurementInterval;
    private TextBox txtBuffersCompleted;
    private Label lblBuffersDone;
    private DataGrid OlBufferDataGrid;
    private Button btnStart;
    private Button btnStop;
    #endregion "Windows Form Designer generated code"
    #region "variables"
    private DataTable OlBufferDataTable;
    private Device device = null;
    private DeviceMgr deviceMgr = DeviceMgr.Get();
    #endregion "variables"
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CultureInfo english = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = english;

    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (device != null)
            {
                device.Dispose();
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
    [STAThread]
    private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
        }
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] deviceNames = deviceMgr.GetDeviceNames();
        for (int i = 0; i < deviceNames.Length; ++i)
        {
            cmbdevice.Items.Add(deviceNames[i]);
        }
        if (cmbdevice.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            cmbdevice.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        OlBufferDataTable = new DataTable("OlBuffer");
        OlBufferDataGrid.DataSource = OlBufferDataTable;
        DataRow newRow;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            newRow = OlBufferDataTable.NewRow();
            OlBufferDataTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
        }
        cboSignalType.Items.Add("Sine");
        cboSignalType.Items.Add("Ramp");
        cboSignalType.Items.Add("Square");
        cboSignalType.Items.Add("txt file");
    }
    private void btnInitialise_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        d.weergeven();
    }
}

public class DeviceClass
{
    public void weergeven()
    {
        string deviceName = (string)cmbdevice.SelectedItem;
        try
        {
            if (device != null)
            {
                device.Dispose();
            }
            device = deviceMgr.GetDevice(deviceName);
            ainSS = device.AnalogInputSubsystem(0);
            ainSS.DriverRunTimeErrorEvent += new DriverRunTimeErrorEventHandler(HandleDriverRunTimeErrorEvent);
            ainSS.DriverRunTimeErrorEvent += new DriverRunTimeErrorEventHandler(HandleDriverRunTimeErrorEvent);
            ainSS.BufferDoneEvent += new BufferDoneHandler(HandleBufferDone);
            ainSS.QueueDoneEvent += new QueueDoneHandler(HandleQueueDone);
            ainSS.QueueStoppedEvent += new QueueStoppedHandler(HandleQueueStopped);
            aoutSS = device.AnalogOutputSubsystem(0);
            aoutSS.DataFlow = DataFlow.Continuous;

            aoutSS.DriverRunTimeErrorEvent += new DriverRunTimeErrorEventHandler(HandleDriverRunTimeErrorEvent);
            aoutSS.BufferDoneEvent += new BufferDoneHandler(HandleBufferDone);
            aoutSS.QueueDoneEvent += new QueueDoneHandler(HandleQueueDone);
            aoutSS.QueueStoppedEvent += new QueueStoppedHandler(HandleQueueStopped);
            aoutSS.IOCompleteEvent += new IOCompleteHandler(HandleIOComplete);
            signalList = new short[aoutSS.NumberOfChannels];

            for (int i = 0; i < aoutSS.NumberOfChannels; ++i)
            {
                if (aoutSS.SupportedChannels[i].SubsystemType != SubsystemType.AnalogOutput)
                    continue;
                cboChannels.Items.Add(i.ToString());
                cboEntry.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }
            cboEntry.SelectedIndex = 0;
            cboChannels.SelectedIndex = 0;
            statusBarPanel.Text = "Output configured without error";
            string name;
            cmbCouplingType.Items.Clear();
            cmbCurrentSource.Items.Clear();
            cmbSyncMode.Items.Clear();

            if (ainSS.SupportsSynchronization)
            {
                string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(SynchronizationModes));

                for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
                    cmbSyncMode.Items.Add(names[i]);

                cmbSyncMode.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                cmbSyncMode.Items.Add("NotSupported");
                this.cmbSyncMode.Enabled = false;
                cmbSyncMode.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            if (ainSS.SupportsDCCoupling || ainSS.SupportsACCoupling)
            {
                if (ainSS.SupportsDCCoupling)
                {
                    name = Enum.GetName(typeof(CouplingType), CouplingType.DC);
                    cmbCouplingType.Items.Add(name);
                    cmbCouplingType.SelectedIndex = cmbCouplingType.Items.IndexOf(name);
                }
                if (ainSS.SupportsACCoupling)
                {
                    name = Enum.GetName(typeof(CouplingType), CouplingType.AC);
                    cmbCouplingType.Items.Add(name);
                    cmbCouplingType.SelectedIndex = cmbCouplingType.Items.IndexOf(name);
                }
                this.cmbCouplingType.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cmbCouplingType.Items.Add("NotSupported");
                this.cmbCouplingType.Enabled = false;
                cmbCouplingType.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            if (ainSS.SupportsExternalExcitationCurrentSrc || ainSS.SupportsInternalExcitationCurrentSrc)
            {
                if (ainSS.SupportsExternalExcitationCurrentSrc)
                {
                    name = Enum.GetName(typeof(ExcitationCurrentSource), ExcitationCurrentSource.External);
                    cmbCurrentSource.Items.Add(name);
                    cmbCurrentSource.SelectedIndex = cmbCouplingType.Items.IndexOf(name);
                }
                if (ainSS.SupportsInternalExcitationCurrentSrc)
                {
                    name = Enum.GetName(typeof(ExcitationCurrentSource), ExcitationCurrentSource.Internal);
                    cmbCurrentSource.Items.Add(name);
                    cmbCurrentSource.SelectedIndex = cmbCurrentSource.Items.IndexOf(name);
                }
                name = Enum.GetName(typeof(ExcitationCurrentSource), ExcitationCurrentSource.Disabled);
                cmbCurrentSource.Items.Add(name);
                cmbCurrentSource.Enabled = true;
                cmbCurrentSource.SelectedItem = "Disabled";
            }
            else
            {
                cmbCurrentSource.Items.Add("NotSupported");
                cmbCurrentSource.Enabled = false;
                cmbCurrentSource.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }

            if (ainSS.SupportsSimultaneousSampleHold)
            {
                statusBarPanel.Text = "Analog input subsystem supports simultaneous sample and hold data acquiring";
            }
        }
        catch (OlException ex)
        {
            string err = ex.Message;
            statusBarPanel.Text = err;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do:
Pass your form as an object to the class

In your form make a method for altering the UI
(for example:

```
public void WriteTextBox(string ToWrite)
{
    TextBoxName.Text = ToWrite;
}
```

)

Call this method from your main form